# Shortcut to define instance method?

Tags: ruby

Ruby has shortcut for defining class methods

```rb
def String.some
  true
end

p String.some
```

Is there similar shortcut to define instance methods?

```rb
def <???>.some
  true
end

p "".some
```

P.S. Also can you please mention link to docs about that shortcut syntax.

Comment: That's not a "shortcut", it's just a side-effect of how method definitions work. There is no specific documentation about this shortcut, just the general concept that methods are defined on objects: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ruby has shortcut for defining class methods
>
> ```rb
> def String.some
>   true
> end
>
> p String.some
> ```

That's not a class method. Ruby doesn't have class methods. That's just a normal singleton method, except that the object it is defined on happens to be an instance of the `Class` class. We simply use the term "class method" to refer to "singleton method of an object that happens to be an instance of the `Class` class" because that is shorter to say, but in the Ruby programming language, there is no such thing as a class method.

And there's no reason the object has to be an instance of the `Class` class, it can be (almost) any object (as long as it is not frozen or immediate):

```ruby
some_obj = Object.new

def some_obj.foo = :bar

some_obj.foo
#=> :bar
```

Except … I lied above. Ruby doesn't have singleton methods either. That's just an instance method of the singleton class of `some_obj`. We simply use the term "singleton method" to refer to "instance method of the singleton class" because that is shorter to say, but in the Ruby programming language, there is no such thing as a singleton method. (There a couple of methods in the *core library* that talk about singleton methods, but they all just operate on instance methods of the singleton class. Again, it's convenient to talk about them, but they fundamentally don't exist.)

Similarly, we talk about "class methods" because that's easier to say "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of the `Class` class", but fundamentally, class methods don't exist.

> Is there similar shortcut to define instance methods?

What you wrote above *does* define instance methods. `some` is an instance method of the singleton class of `String`:

```ruby
String.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:try_convert, :some]
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use singleton method like shown below

```
instance = "Rajagopalan"
def instance.some_instance_method
  puts "Hi, this is Rajagopalan"
end

instance.some_instance_method
```

This wouldn't work for numeric. If you would like to add for Numeric object, then you can open the Numeric class like this and add your method over there

```
class MyNumeric < Numeric
  def some_instance_method
    "it's a numeric value"
  end
end

instance = MyNumeric.new
puts instance.some_instance_method
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def String.some
  true
end
```

This is a shortcut to add a singleton method to an object. Any object works and `String` or `"str"` both are objects, just of different classes.

*https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Scope*

---

As far as the shortcut for instance method, there is a method for that:

```
String.define_method(:some) { "some " + self }

>> "say".some
=> "some say"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're trying to add an instance method to some class after the class is already defined.

In Ruby you can reopen the class to define extra stuff within it. It's called ["monkey patching"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). Here's an example:

```rb
class String
  def with_greeting
    "Hello #{self}"
  end
end

"Anon".with_greeting # => "Hello Anon"

# Existing methods of String still work:
"Anon".size # => 4
```

Alternatively, you can use [`#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Module.html#method-i-define_method) like this:

```rb
String.define_method(:with_bye) { "Bye #{self}" }

"Anon".with_bye # => "Bye Anon"
```